# Is there a way to append something to every link on a page with css/html?

Tags: html, css

I'm making a CSS theme for my site and I want all links to have a certain appendage after them (`/theme_fullname/theme:light`). How can I do this, or can I at all?

For example a link to `http://example-site.com/lorem-ipsum` would become `http://example-site.com/lorem-ipsum/theme_fullname/theme:light`.

Comment: I think mean you want to achieve that with HTML not CSS

Comment: What do you want to add to all links? Can you give an example of a link before and after of what you want please. What have you tried?